# C# Socket - How to get the number of times the client connects to the server per minutes?

Tags: c#, sockets

I am writing a socket server and I need to know how many times a user connects to my socket (server) per minute.
I tried for about 2 days to look for information on the various forums, unfortunately I could not find anything, I hope this community can help me with this, if my question is not clear, then please write about it in the comments.

```
if (Core.OnlineUsers.FindAll((Predicate<Client>) (x => x.IPAddress == IP)).Count > 10)
        {
          _Socket.Dispose();
        }
```

I need to do this so that the socket is not dropped from the connections, because if there are too many connections, can not connect to it.

Comment: FYI an IP address is not a unique user - there can be multiple users within the same building all sharing an IP address.

Comment: @riffnl, Yes, it can, but I don't have that many connections, about 30, so I think that if  make a connection filter, you can protect the socket

Comment: If you only have about 30 why does the connection drop?

Comment: @riffnl A year ago I had a problem with frequent connections from the same IP address, so I think you need to do some kind of filter.